# Custom windows skin,

Tags: c++, windows

What is the best way to create a custom skin for an application the way google chrome has done in Windows using native API?

I'm writing an opengl app and would like to have all the windows borders, min, max button and caption bar handled by the app.. I tried using CreateWindowEx to create a borderless window, however when I add the WS_SYSMENU style, the title bar appears and min/max system menu items are disabled...

Comment: Download the source code for Chromium and look at how they've done it. It's completely open source, and there's no better way to reimplement something similar in your own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to handle the WM_NC* methods, including WM_NCPAINT, WM_NCHITTEST, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, etc.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check it out. Would you be able to point me to a tutorial or sample code that does this?